# Knockout.js 'foreach' binding for a linked list

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Just curious, how might one go about creating a 'foreach' binding that iterates over a linked list the way the current 'foreach' binding iterates over arrays?

I've created [a jsFiddle for tinkering](http://jsfiddle.net/bmh_ca/uCyDG/1/).

I think a linked list could be a useful idiom to use with Knockout.js. In particular, if done right the DOM would only updated for elements that are being added/removed (i.e. the whole list is not updated when an element is added/removed), and the adding/removing to the middle of the list has complexity of O(1), versus O(n) for an array.

Answer (score 1):

Array based foreach is already very performant; DOM elements are added/removed only as nessesary; Of course, the whole Array is scanned for changes but it's pretty quick (ko only have coarse change signals for array). Random insertions or deletions are fast thanks to the distance algorithm used.

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice idea, but unfortunately I don't think it's possible.

You would have to subscribe to the observable for the head of the list and the 'next' observable for every element.

The problem is that you don't gain any advantage unless you can tell which one of the observables triggered the change. If you edit something in the middle of the list the whole point is that the foreach binding needs to be able to update that part of the DOM without having to iterate the entire structure. Bindings don't currently allow this- if a binding subscribes to multiple observables its `update` method will be called if any of them change, without knowing which of them changed.

Also, even if this could work, all those extra ko.observable() structures and subscriptions would be quite a serious overhead. Three observables instead of just having another array element.

To avoid unnecessary changes to the DOM you could compare the new structure with the old and just make the relevant changes, but this can be done when using arrays anyway (I don't think the built-in foreach binding makes this optimisation).

Comment: Thanks for the post. I don't understand the problem in paragraph 3 - could you elaborate please? Why would you need the observable that triggered the change? Do you mean the previous element? I'd expect this structure would be necessarily a 2-way linked list (for this and other reasons), which might solve the issue you are concerned with? How much of a concern is the overhead of all the ko.observables - I had thought (perhaps mistakenly) that they were quite lightweight - except unless they are at the bottom of a subscription tier, which these iterators shouldn't be.

Comment: Could an alternative approach be to have a `computed` observable which traverses the linked list, putting each element into a flat, ordered, array, then you could `foreach` on that. Would this allow you to achieve what you wanted?

Comment: I've updated the answer. I don't see how making it a `computed` helps, that just makes it a very expensive array. I am unable to see any reason not to just use an array in the first place. There is definitely space for a new binding that doesn't update that section DOM from scratch, but it would still use an array.